# Look-up a key in an object with exhaustiveness check with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typechecking

Say my server responds with the following: 'a', 'b', or 'c'. These map to 'alpha', 'beta' or 'gamma' in my app. If I were using JS, I'd do the following to translate:

```js
const mapping = {
  a: 'alpha',
  b: 'beta',
  c: 'gamma'
}

const lookUp = serverResponse => mapping[serverResponse];
```

I can do the equivalent in TypeScript. However, let's say I also want the guarantee that in case the server adds 'd' for 'delta', I can modify one location in my code and let TS help me with its type system to guide the rest of my refactoring.

```js
type ServerResponse = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type ActualMeaning = 'alpha' | 'beta' | 'gamma';

const mapping: { [key in ServerResponse]: ActualMeaning } = {
  a: 'alpha',
  b: 'beta',
  c: 'gamma'
} as const;

const shouldNeverReachHere = (x: never): never => {
  throw new Error(`This value not exhaustively handled: ${x}`);
}

const lookup = (serverResponse: ServerResponse): ActualMeaning => {
  if (serverResponse in mapping) return mapping[serverResponse];
  return shouldNeverReachHere(serverResponse);
}
```

I'd expect that since the `mapping` is known at compile time (because of the `as const`), the exhaustiveness check for `shouldNeverReachHere(serverResponse)` would have worked. However, I get the following error for that line:

```
Argument of type '"a" | "b" | "c" is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'never'. ts(2345)
```

If I change the function to use a `switch` instead of looking up in an object, it works. But `switch` statements are clunky. I also want to convert both ways, which makes objects very easy to work with, as opposed to a `switch`.

Any idea how I could make the above code work in TypeScript?

Comment: you should know by now that you can't just make up tags for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about *exhaustiveness check*, but in this case `ServerResponse` is incompatible with `never`.

Try this definition of your abort function:

```js
const shouldNeverReachHere = (x: unknown): never => {
    throw new Error(`This value not exhaustively handled: ${x}`);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhBOA3BAlCBnMB7Adu6AvFAOQCGxUAPiQEYXXEDGxA3AFCiRQCCjwArqQA2AWQikcASxwBzKETJCwAC3JVaEYGoYzSAWz3l2bRrnTAohsGGkyAXFADeUANoBrCCCjTYCZPDRMMwgAXQdeAWExCVsoAF95JzYoKFIHRRVyABpkqBp0mk1s3MZ03QNyNjjjUzwLdGUsfiEAEwA5CH80UkZlAAkEQigACgAPB34cNxwsAHccAEoHHE6EeQA+JJTgZXg5qBXZqABReD34YYADABVlSXQoRGF+aBmLCFHVfnNJZCEvVQ4FpCCAtBwAEkcozilwW7DibBMZgsQiwWDc-DAiWG+CQqAw2DwEAccDxAQJwSWPD4glE4iksg2W28ADMRriuhSid4cJZSNZbAsoPBNPx4LyrDZZC4OfigkSQuwUiKBOKoA0mq0Opyev1Bji-HLCfg4VUgA)

Comment: No, the `(x: never)` is intentional. It's so that when I add a new item to the `ServerResponse`, say `d`, and I forget to add `delta` to `ActualMeaning`, I want the compiler to complain, since `x` won't be `never`. See the `assertNever` function here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#exhaustiveness-checking

Comment: Got it. I though your intention was "just to compile this code".

Nevertheless i think you're trying to validate on wrong level. The check for missing `d` is already there - try adding it to enum and you'll see error on `mapping`. Second, by declaring `lookup(x: ServerResponse)` you're basically saying that `x` is really `ServerResponse`. You cannot `lookup("foo")` or stuff. So i think that you don't need any `if` or `shouldNeverReachHere` in `lookup`. Insead, you if you expect invalid input from server you should validate `serverResponse` eariler.